# Getting user login and logout information in AWS CloudTrail

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudtrail

I have enabled CloudTrail using the AWS Management Console and the Amazon S3 Bucket policies are the defaults ones that are created automatically when enabling CloudTrail.

I can find logs about my log-in along with all other even logs **but there is no information about log-off**. Is there something I need to do for it or its simply not there? Doesn't log-off classify as an event?

**Edit 1**

I am new to CloudTrail, and trying to understand what is possible and what not. I have a IAM User which only read-write access to one bucket and list all buckets. When using it I invoked `aws ec2 describe-instances` I can see in log that `errorCode: "Client.UnauthorizedOperation"`, but when I do a `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 ls` and its a success, it is not logged. Here is the default bucket policy created.

```js
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20131101",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::903692715234:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::859597730677:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::814480443879:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::216624486486:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::086441151436:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::388731089494:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::284668455005:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::113285607260:root"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20131101",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::903692715234:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::859597730677:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::814480443879:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::216624486486:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::086441151436:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::388731089494:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::284668455005:root",
                "arn:aws:iam::113285607260:root"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/MY_PREFIX/AWSLogs/MY_ACCOUNT_ID/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

And where and why did that so may `Principal` come from - they aren't my accounts, they were created by AWS when I enabled CloudTrail. Are these AWS Accounts that deliver logs to my bucket, should they be there?

**Edit 2**

From [typepad's post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/aws-cloudtrail-capture-aws-api-activity.html), logging for S3 is not yet there. And the log-in that I see is actually because of the AWS Security Token Service (STS) `GetSessionToken` call. In case of a log-out from the console it seems there is no call to STS, hence no resulting log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As every so often, AWS has listened to customer demand for *greater visibility into when users sign in to the AWS Management Console* and just announced that [AWS CloudTrail Now Logs AWS Management Console Sign-In Events](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1RRJBQRA9MQOI/AWS-CloudTrail-Now-Logs-AWS-Management-Console-Sign-In-Events), thereby obsoleting the indirect method via `GetSessionToken` and replacing it with explicit and more detailed events:

> Logging successful and unsuccessful console sign-in events for AWS IAM
>   and federated users can help you with your compliance and security
>   efforts. With this new feature, you get the following for both IAM and
>   federated users:
>
> - Every successful sign-in.
> - Every unsuccessful sign-in attempt.
> - Verification of when multi-factor authentication (MFA) was enforced.
> - The IP address of every sign-in event.
>
> Additionally, you can see a record of every time a root account successfully signs in. Finally,
>   you can see when an IAM user has not signed in for a period of time,
>   suggesting that you might be able to remove that IAM user.

Unfortunately there's still no visibility in logout events though.